# truffle script:Cant retrieve the transaction receipt, dont know how to get transaction sender and receiver

Tags: truffle, truffle-console

I am executing the following script, I don't know how to retrieve the sender and receiver from the transaction receipt. I am trying to retrieve the transaction receipt but it does not work.

```
// Contracts
const  MySC1 = artifacts.require("MySC1")
const MySC2 = artifacts.require("MySC2")

module.exports = async function(callback) {
try {
    // Fetch accounts from wallet - these are unlocked
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    // Set up account to transferEther to Victim
    const acc2 = accounts[2]
    acc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
    web3.utils.fromWei(acc2bal, "ether")
    console.log('acc2 balance', acc2bal, 'address',acc2)
    // Fetch the deployed exchange
    const sc1 = await MySC1.deployed()
    console.log('SC1 deployed', sc1.address)
    const sc2 = await MySC2.deployed()
    console.log('SC2 deployed', sc2.address)
    sc1bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(sc1.address)
    web3.utils.fromWei(sc1bal, "ether")
    console.log(`Initial SC1:`,sc1.address,` balance is ${sc1bal}`)
    sc2bal = await web3.eth.getBalance(sc2.address)
    web3.utils.fromWei(sc2bal, "ether")
    console.log(`Initial SC2:`,sc2.address,` balance is ${sc2bal}`)
    amount = '11'
    result = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sc1.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei(amount)})
    result.receipt
}
  catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }

  callback()
}
```

The SCs for sender and receiver are:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract MySC1 {

    address owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendTo(address payable receiver, uint amount) public {
        (bool success,) = receiver.call.value(amount)("");
        require(success);
    }

    function() external payable{
     }

}
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;
interface MySC1{
   function sendTo(address payable to, uint amount) external;
}
contract MySC2 {
    uint public cnt;
    //This contract will receive Ether sent by MyContract
    address owner;

    constructor() public {
       owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() external payable {
       //cnt++;
      //if(cnt < 2) {
      //   MySC1(msg.sender).sendTo(address(this), msg.sender.balance);
       //}          
    }
}
```

Somebody please guide me how to retrieve the transaction receipt, and the sender and receiver of the transaction.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the transaction receipt object, sender, and receiver, you can do this at the end of the script :

```
result = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:sc1.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei(amount)})
console.log("receipt : ", result)
console.log("sender : ", result.from)
console.log("receiver : ", result.to)
```

You can find more info about the web3 `sendTrannsaction` function behavior here : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction.

Comment: @@clement: if I do: result = await sc1.sendTo(sc2.address, web3.utils.toWei(amount,"ether"), {from:accounts[0]})
    console.log("receipt : ", result)
    console.log("sender : ", result.from)
    console.log("receiver : ", result.to)
    console.log(`Deposited ${amount} Ether from sc1:`, sc1.address), I am getting the transaction receipt but sender and receiver are undefined: '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.....00000000000000000000000000000000',
     rawLogs: [] }, 
  logs: [] }
receiver :  undefined, please guide me, Zulfi.